# Transport Layer - Start & End Bytes

Tags: segments

Scenario:

Alice sends a message to Bob which is 4500 bytes long, and is broken into segments of 1000 bytes each. Alice chooses a random start value of 3300 for her sequence numbers.

Q. Give the start and end bytes of each segment ?

This is basically for revision purposes and really struggling to understand. If anyone can shed some light on this for me it would be really appreciated